# Como adicionar variável à array [JS]

Tags: javascript, array

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
var newLat = markerElem.getAttribute('lat');
var newLng = markerElem.getAttribute('lng');

var locations = [
    {lat: newLat, lng: newLng}
]
```

Quero pegar os valores das variáveis `newLat` e `newLng` e guardá-las dentro do array `locations` como valores dos seus respectivos índices.

**EXEMPLO**

Quero que sejam passados os valores das variáveis `newLat` e `newLng` para os índices do array `lat` e `lng`, ficando assim:

```
var newLat = 123;
var newLng = 321;

var locations = [
    {lat: 123, lng: 321}
]
```

Comment: Não entendi pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Pode melhorar a explicação?
Você deseja adicionar as variáveis ao array ou criar um array das variáveis?

Comment: Vou dar um exemplo para ficar mais claro

Comment: Se o seu desejo for adicionar ao array faça

`locations.push({ lat: newLat , lng: newLng});`

O javascript vai adicionar um novo indíce no seu array e depois para recuperá-lo basta percorrer ele.

Comment: Lucas Brogni, seu código deu certo, só tive que passar os valores para float. Responda ao meu post com este comentário para marcá-lo como resolvido.

Comment: @HigorCardoso respondi lá. Hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o seu desejo for adicionar ao array faça

```
locations.push({ lat: newLat , lng: newLng});
```

O javascript vai adicionar um novo indíce no seu array e depois para recuperá-lo basta percorrer ele.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode alterar os valores desta forma:

```js
var locations = [
    {lat: '', lng: ''}
]

var markerElem = document.getElementById("div");
var newLat = markerElem.getAttribute('lat');
var newLng = markerElem.getAttribute('lng');

locations[0].lat = newLat; // altera lat
locations[0].lng = newLng; // altera lng

console.log(locations);
```

```html
<div id="div" lat="123" lng="456"></div>
```

`locations[0]` seleciona o primeiro índice da array.

Se quer adicionar um novo índice à array, pode fazer desta forma:

```js
var locations = [];

var markerElem = document.getElementById("div");
var lat = markerElem.getAttribute('lat');
var lng = markerElem.getAttribute('lng');

locations.push({ lat , lng });

console.log(locations);
```

```html
<div id="div" lat="123" lng="456"></div>
```

> Colocando apenas o nome da variável, já é adicionado o nome e o valor
>   da variável como chave do objeto na array.